# Possible to change the behavior of double-clicking a minimized taskbar button?

Tags: windows, taskbar, gui

In Windows, double-clicking a minimized taskbar button shows the application window.

Is it possible to **change that behavior to instead show, then minimize** the application window?

**Edit**

It's likely the answer is, *It's not possible* -- and that would be an acceptable answer. If you know that's the right answer, please post it.